# TI SensorTag 2 CC2650 Servis Calculations (IR temperature - MPU9250)

Tags: swift, sensors

How can I calculate IR temperature in CC2650.

TI Temperature : F000AA00-0451-4000-B000-000000000000

Temperature Data: f000aa01-0451-4000-b000-000000000000

I try to calculate object and ambient based on data in Temperature Data characteristic. Object data is higher then IR temperature showed in TI application.

Swift Code:

```
 static func calculateObjectAndAmbient(objectRaw:Int16, ambientRaw:Int16) -> (Double, Double)
    {
        let ambient = Double(ambientRaw)/128.0;
        let vObj2 = Double(objectRaw)*0.00000015625;
        let tDie2 = ambient + 273.15;
        let s0 = 6.4*pow(10,-14);
        let a1 = 1.75*pow(10,-3);
        let a2 = -1.678*pow(10,-5);
        let b0 = -2.94*pow(10,-5);
        let b1 = -5.7*pow(10,-7);
        let b2 = 4.63*pow(10,-9);
        let c2 = 13.4;
        let tRef = 298.15;
        let s = s0*(1+a1*(tDie2 - tRef)+a2*pow((tDie2 - tRef),2));
        let vOs = b0 + b1*(tDie2 - tRef) + b2*pow((tDie2 - tRef),2);
        let fObj = (vObj2 - vOs) + c2*pow((vObj2 - vOs),2);
        let object = pow(pow(tDie2,4) + (fObj/s),0.25) - 273.15;
        return (object, ambient)
    }
```

I also want to calculate MPU9250Service data.

Service = "F000AA80-0451-4000-B000-000000000000"

Characteristic Data = "F000AA81-0451-4000-B000-000000000000"

Characteristic Config = "F000AA82-0451-4000-B000-000000000000"

Is there a manual ? I would like to access Gyro., Accel., Magn., data.

Sorry about my english.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Voting to close this question as it's unclear what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculation of Object and Ambient is changed in CC2650.

So new swift calculations in here if anyone needed;

```
   static func calculateObjectAndAmbient(objectRaw:Int16, ambientRaw:Int16) -> (Double, Double)
    {
        let SCALE_LSB = 0.03125;
        let a = objectRaw >> 2;
        let Obj = Double(a) * SCALE_LSB

        let b = ambientRaw >> 2;
        let Amb = Double(b) * SCALE_LSB
        return (Obj, Amb)
   }
```

More Details : [sensortag2015](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/wireless_connectivity/sensortag2015/tearDown.html)

More Details : [TI Wiki](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC2650_SensorTag_User's_Guide#IR_Temperature_Sensor)